# Flatlist onContentSizeChange scrolls to different position

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist

i have a chat application in react native using flatlist component, here i use the code..

```
                ref={flatlistRef}
                onContentSizeChange={() => flatlistRef.current.scrollToEnd({})}
                onLayout={() => flatlistRef.current.scrollToEnd({})}
                onScroll={
                    (event) =>
                        onContentOffsetChanged(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y)
                }
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id + index.toString()}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                    <ChatListView
                        index={index}
                        message={item.message}
                        sender={item.senderUserID}
                        msgTime={item.timestamp}
                    />
                )}
            />
```

Now i have three condition on the first render it goes to the last message and then when user scroll to the top then new messages are pushed to the list and here flatlist not to scroll automaticaaly but when ther only one message added it should again scroll to end, Please help in my code it always scroll to end when content size changed , which is not required for the case when user go to the top most message and newly 30 messages are added and it occurs due to

`onContentSizeChange={() => flatlistRef.current.scrollToEnd({})}`

but not customize for that case please help what to do here?